# Build a Linq statement with IsNullOrEmpty check

Tags: c#, linq

How can I build a single Linq statement where it check returns all records unless the param is passed? If param is empty then ignore specific 'where'.

I have tried using `IsNullOrEmpty` within the WHERE but I get an error.

Here are the NON-REQUIRED form field for searching for Invoices.

*Invoice Id, Check Number, State Issued*

```
var invoices = ctx.Invoices; <-- get all invoiced

if (inputInvoiceId > 0)
invoices = from i in invoices
where i.id == inputInvoiceId
select i;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputCheckNumber))
invoices = from i in invoices
where i.checkNumber == inputCheckNumber
select i;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputState))
invoices = from i in invoices
where i.state == inputState
select i;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could build your query by conditionally appending `where` clauses like this:

```
var invoices = ctx.Invoices.AsQueryable();

if (inputInvoiceId > 0)
    invoices = invoices.Where(x => x.id == inputInvoiceId);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputCheckNumber))
    invoices = invoices.Where(x => x.checkNumber == inputCheckNumber);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputState))
    invoices = invoices.Where(x => x.state == inputState);

return invoices.ToList();
```

Each additional `where` clause further filters your results, but the query itself won't be executed (nor any data retrieved) until you call `ToList()`.

Answer (score 1):

What @GrantWinney said will work.  Alternatively, you can deal with it in a single query, which may or may not have query compilation/cache benefits if you are concerned about such things:

```
// Query short-circuit parameters
var invoiceNotSpecified = inputVoiceId == 0;
var checkNumberNotSpecificed = String.IsNullOrEmpty(inputCheckNumber);
var stateNotSpecified = String.IsNullOrEmpty(inputState);

// Query
var invoices = from i in ctx.Invoices
     where (invoiceNotSpeficied || i.id == inputInvoiceId) && 
      (checkNumberNotSpecified || i.checkNumber == inputCheckNumber) && 
      (stateNotSpecified || i.state == inputState)
     select i;
```